# Intel assembly language from Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, programming

I just want to know if its possible to run assembly language programme, that I was running on windows os using tasm, on ubuntu (linux environment).

I actually removed windows completely from my laptop and currently running ubuntu.The problem here is that I have in my syllabus,assembly language programming in Intel 8086 microprocessor. Is there any way I can run those programs here in ubuntu? Can I make use of virtualbox. I don't know what I'm saying.

Please enlighten me, friends. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes there are assemblers available for systems that aren't Windows.

Comment: thanks for the reply bro...I know of nasm in ubuntu. will it work out same as the tasm in windows ?

Comment: It's not the same assembler, but generally it should produce the same output, for the same assembler code, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are compilers capable of assembling Intel 8086 architecture code. as86 is one example

`sudo apt-get install as86`

You may have to change how you call library routines as some interfaces would be different between operating systems.

8086 instructions can be expressed differently to different assemblers, so that's something to watch.